# Заменить значение background-image в style

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вообщем суть такая. В скрипте слайдер выводит информацию так:

```
 <div class="beautypress-welcome-slider-item content-<?php echo esc_attr($alignment); ?> beautypress-bg" style="background-image: url(<?php echo esc_url($image); ?>);">
```

Мне нужно заменить значение из поля background-image на мое значение (вручную прописать путь).

Тобишь скрипт выводит слайдер, там 3 разных слайда, с разным background-image, на него накладывается текст и тд. На ПК отображается все нормально, а вот в телефоне мне не нравится, хочу для мобильных телефонов выводить определенный background-image для всех 3 слайдов один и тот же background-image.

Допустим `background-image: url(<?php echo esc_url($image); ?>);` выводит значение `background-image: url("/img/fon1.jpg");`

Логика такая:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
width = $(window).width();
if (width >= 700) {
    //Здесь код, который заменит получившиеся значение в ходе выполнения цикла php background-image: url(/img/fon1.jpg); на значение background-image: url("/img/moy-fon.jpg");
}
```

});

P.S. Вот условие полное:

```
<script>
// делаете переменную в начале кода
var isMobile = false;
// проверка на размер экрана (размер я брал вроде с Bootstrap-а)
$(document).ready( function() {
    if ($('body').width() <= 700) {
        isMobile = true;
    }
    // и потом если нужен код только для телефона:
    if (isMobile) {
(function($) {

                var imageUrl = '/img/fon-mobile.jpg';

                $('.beautypress-welcome-slider-item').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');

}(jQuery));
    }
    // или для остальных
    if (!isMobile) {

    }
} );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример изменения `background`:

```js
(function($) {

  var imageUrl = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/36a0fa29702c895fb254590089610cee?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1';

  $('.beautypress-welcome-slider-item').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');

}(jQuery));
```

```css
.beautypress-welcome-slider-item {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 15px;
    border: 1px solid;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="beautypress-welcome-slider-item" style="background-image: url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2196b16903565e17033335bcd641d447?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1');"></div>
  <div class="beautypress-welcome-slider-item" style="background-image: url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2196b16903565e17033335bcd641d447?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1');"></div>
  <div class="beautypress-welcome-slider-item" style="background-image: url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2196b16903565e17033335bcd641d447?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1');"></div>  
</div>
```

Пример с нужным для Вас условием:

```js
(function($) {
  $(window).resize(function(event) {
    var width = window.innerWidth,
        widthValue = 700,
        imageUrl = '';

    if (width <= widthValue) {
      imageUrl = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2196b16903565e17033335bcd641d447?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1';
    } else {
      imageUrl = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/36a0fa29702c895fb254590089610cee?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1';
    } 

    $('.beautypress-welcome-slider-item').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
  });
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.beautypress-welcome-slider-item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 15px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="beautypress-welcome-slider-item" style="background-image: url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2196b16903565e17033335bcd641d447?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1');"></div>
  <div class="beautypress-welcome-slider-item" style="background-image: url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2196b16903565e17033335bcd641d447?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1');"></div>
  <div class="beautypress-welcome-slider-item" style="background-image: url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2196b16903565e17033335bcd641d447?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1');"></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: А что элемент с тегом `main-container`?

Comment: Подозреваю, что это название класса, в который вставляется background-image. В данном примере это вообще никак не применимо.

Comment: @КириллДмитриевич Вам нужно заменить, `background` у определенных элементов, или у одного? В любом случае, вы можете подставить вместо `main-container` то, что Вам нужно, и все будет работать.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko `main-container` это просто пример, его можно заменить.

Comment: Заменил `main-container` на `.beautypress-welcome-slider-item`. Так будет понятнее.

Comment: @Dmitry $('.beautypress-welcome-slider-item').css('background-image', 'url(https://site.ru/img/fon-mobile.jpg)'); Вы так имели ввиду? Просто пустое место появлятся

Comment: @КириллДмитриевич я Вас понял, сейчас изменю ответ, сделаю его более подробнее.

Comment: @КириллДмитриевич изменил. Надеюсь теперь это Вам поможет. Только я условие не добавлял. Добавите уже самостоятельно.

Comment: Я намекал на то, что у вас селектор не был классом. Точка отсутствовала. Теперь гораздо лучше ответ!

Comment: @Dmitry спасибо, почти получилось, но не работает внутри условия. Вместо слайдера дает белый лист. Код с условием добавил в стартовый пост.

Comment: @КириллДмитриевич то что оно у Вас не работает, внутри условия, это уже другой вопрос =) Через некоторое время просмотрю что у Вас у не выходит

Comment: @Dmitry спасибо, буду ждать))

Comment: @Dmitry уже миллион разных условий пробовал, убирал скобочки и тд. Все безрезультатно. Если удастся решить, то отпишусь сюда)

Comment: @КириллДмитриевич готово.

Comment: @Dmitry спасибо огромное))